# Enabling JBoss AS 7 Directory Listings

Tags: jboss7.x

I have the following directory structure deployed to JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final (under `standalone/deployments`):

```
doc.war
    -> module1
        -> index.html
    -> module2
        -> index.html
```

As you can see, there's no index.html under doc.war. When I browse to **localhost:8080/doc/module1/**, the correct index.html is displayed, but when I browse to **localhost:8080/doc/**, JBoss shows an error message (*404 - The requested resource is not available*).

I think this is related to the fact that directory listings are turned off by default in JBoss AS 7. How can I enable directory listings, either globally or more specifically for this one application?

**Edit**

Based on Mukul Goel's answer, I ran the CLI command to add the *static-resources* feature, restarted the server and retried the request, but it didn't work.

Here's the relevant snippet from the `standalone.xml` file. Please note that I have the *native* connector enabled.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="true">
    <configuration>
        <static-resources listings="true"/>
    </configuration>
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Here's the error message that JBoss is showing:

[image: JBoss Error Message]

**Update**

So the conclusion to this seems to be that there is an issue with the official JBoss 7.1.1.Final (http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads) download. I didn't manage to get Directory Listings working with this version. Trying a later version (from the JBoss CI server at https://ci.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS-7.x-latest/), I was able to see the directory listings after applying the config change that Mukul Goel had suggested below.

A potential source of this issue could be the version of JBossWeb that is used in JBoss. The official 7.1.1.Final bundles JBossWeb 7.0.13. Mukul (see below) was able to get it working running a version of JBoss that bundles JBossWeb 7.0.16.

I'm accepting Mukul Goel's answer as solving this issue, but be aware that it will probably not work with the official 7.1.1.Final download.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you are right, directory listings are by default disabled (a security measure)

To enable directory listing in JBOSS

Try running the following CLI command to enable diectory listing:

> **In Domain Mode**
>
> /profile=full/subsystem=web/configuration=static-resources/:write-attribute(name=listings,value=true)

.

> **In Standalone Mode**
>
> /subsystem=web/configuration=static-resources/:write-attribute(name=listings,value=true)

It will generate following kind of configuration :

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">

            <configuration>
                <static-resources listings="true"/>
            </configuration>


            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

UPDATE:
Tried it myself as the user is facing problems

RAN CLI command for the standaloneMode

This was generated, note that the native is disabled also there is no HTTPS connector generated for me (Don`t know why it is showing enabled for you? are you using openSSL somewhere? )

[image: relevant code from standalonex.ml]

I created a sample webprojet(a client side project) with two htmls ,published it to jboss and hit url

```
http://localhost:8080/sample/
```

and this is the screenshot of directory listing

[image: Directory listing screenshot]

The command worked it for me, So that does turns on Directory listing on JBOSS AS7.1.1 Final(I am also using the same version)
So the question comes down to rest of your server configuration, your application structure, technologies you are using, springs etc and also if you are using some ssl library.

**UPDATE 2**
Suggested a fresh download and reconfigure environment and see
nwinkler was still facing issues even with a fresh distribution (JbossWeb 7.0.13) So suggested to take nightly builds from

> ci.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS-7.x-latest
>
> Just go to the link and download whats under last successful artifact

And the problem was resolved. Looks like some bug with jbossWeb 7.0.13

***Do go through the comments, the discussion might be helpful***

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. The same error page comes up. I verified that the standalone.xml file was modified with the change you have noted.

Comment: :-/ , it should be working. 
did you restart your server?
also. you are using HTTP protocol /HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server. The request is done using HTTP. I see there's also a connector for HTTPS in the web subsystem. And the subsystem is enabled to use the 'native' connector. I'll update my post to show the config.

Comment: The `native` should not be enabled. Please mark it false, restart and try

Comment: I tried this again with a fresh version of 7.1.1.Final (unzipped from the .tgz), no other changes. Deployed a simple exploded war file with a structure like I've shown above. No libs, (pretty much) empty web.xml, nothing else. Still doesn't work. I've noticed that yours is running JBoss Web 7.0.16.Final, while mine is 7.0.13.Final ...

Comment: Hmmm.. I dint heard of a "list directory issue with 7.0.13 ( I dint heard that doesnt mean there wasnt any, there could have been an issue.. also its a beta( .13 #odd) , try avoid using odd versions..
@nwinkler download latest jboss 7.1.1 build from jboss comm.. and test.

Comment: That's what I did - I downloaded again from here: http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads - and it contains version 7.0.13 of JBossWeb. Where did you download yours?

Comment: I dint download it from the download page. 
I prefer most recent stable builds, so I downloaded it back in somewhere in august from
https://ci.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS-7.x-latest/

Just go to the link and download whats under `last successful artifact`

Comment: OK, downloaded the latest artifact from there, which identifies itself as 7.2.0.Alpha1 - and the directory listings work there after applying the change you had in your first post. So it looks like the JBossWeb 7.0.13 packaged with the official 7.1.1.Final download has an issue with the directory listings.

Comment: yup. that distribution says 7.2 Alpha1. glad you could have it work.Happy to help you and sort out your problem :-)

yea looks like there is some bug.
would you like to post the case on JBoss AS7 community forum @ https://community.jboss.org/en/jbossas7?view=discussions 
about this ? that directory listing is not working in 7.0.13 (i checked release notes and there is nothing about the same error). so the dev`s working on development could know ?

Comment: Thanks for the awesome help - I've accepted your answer and have added a comment to my question explaining that I couldn't get it to work on the official 7.1.1.Final.